# storm kafka worker log retrying with default start offset time from configuration

Tags: cluster-computing, apache-storm

Run code in local mode (calling the same kafka brokers) fine but as soon as I deploy to cluster I get this weird error in my spout. Any ideas?

error below:

```
 2014-09-17 16:59:55 s.k.KafkaUtils [WARN] Got fetch request with offset out of range: [300]; retrying with default start offset time from configuration. configured start offset time: [-1] offset: [5]

 2014-09-17 16:59:55 s.k.KafkaUtils [WARN] Got fetch request with offset out of range: [300]; retrying with default start offset time from configuration. configured start offset time: [-1] offset: [5]

 2014-09-17 16:59:55 s.k.KafkaUtils [WARN] Got fetch request with offset out of range: [300]; retrying with default start offset time from configuration. configured start offset time: [-1] offset: [5]

 2014-09-17 16:59:55 s.k.KafkaUtils [WARN] Got fetch request with offset out of range: [300]; retrying with default start offset time from configuration. configured start offset time: [-1] offset: [5]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its saying you are requesting a offset which no longer exists .. not sure if I am not wrong you are using KafkaSpout.. if so try to change the start offset time value from `-1` to `-2` which will force it to read from the beginning of the queue. If you are using a different spout implementation than the one I mentioned then look for any settings that allows you to read it from the beginning